# addChild() issue: error 2007 on AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have this piece of code that's suppose to add a `swf` file (homePage.swf) inside my main file (skeleton.fla).

**Code:**

```
var mcHome:MovieClip;

var newPage:Loader = new Loader();
newPage.load(new URLRequest("homePage.swf"));

newPage.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, homeLoaded);      

function homeLoaded(event:Event):void {

    mcHome = MovieClip(newPage.contentLoaderInfo.content);
    newPage.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, homeLoaded);
    addChild(mcHome);  

}
```

I keep getting this error:

> TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null. at
>   flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChild() at
>   skeleton_fla::MainTimeline/homeLoaded()

I don't know how to solve it, or what to change!

Help please, I'm a bit desperate.

Comment: Make sure that "homePage.swf" is in the same directory as your skeleton.fla and check the spelling of the swf file name

Comment: yes, it is. And the name is the same.

Comment: Try `addChild(newPage);`.  eg adding the loader instead of the content of the loader. You wouldn't be getting the complete event if the swf didn't exist.   Most likely it's a security sandbox issue.

Comment: Now I've got this error: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at skeleton_fla::MainTimeline/homeLoaded()

Comment: What does your homeLoaded function look like now?   If you're not doing anything else, you can just use three lines of code:   `var newPage:Loader.....`    -    `newPage.load(new URLRequest.....)`;   -   `addChild(newPage);`   -  then forget the home loaded function and complete listener all together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is better to add to the `displayList` the `Loader` object instead its `contentLoaderInfo.content`. The `Loader` is a `DisplayObject` by itself. There is not need to access to the `MovieClip` inside of the `Loader` object although it is possible in the most of environments.

> If you try to load an `SWF` that resides in other domain, you could add the `Loader` object to the `displayList` but you can't access to the content property if you don't create a `crossdomain.xml` file.

```
var newPage:Loader = new Loader();
newPage.load(new URLRequest("homePage.swf"));

newPage.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, homeLoaded);      

function homeLoaded(event:Event):void {

    newPage.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, homeLoaded);

    addChild(newPage);  

}
```

[Here](http://xprimiendo.com/examples/FLASH/loader.zip) you have an example.

Comment: Consider making your answer more useful by explaining why the loader needs to be added instead of the content.

Comment: Ok @BadFeelingAboutThis, I'll try to train my bad english ;)

Comment: That's actually not true and not even a valid answer despite the fact that it's already marked accepted. There's no valid reason as to why a loader would be better to add than it's loaded content.

Comment: Hi @BotMaster. First of all sorry for my bad english. I don't have the original `SWF` file to see why it happens. But I give you an example that makes fails her code, if you load an `SWF` that have a main class extending the `Sprite` class the code fails when you try to cast the `Sprite` to `MovieClip`. Is better and more easy to me using the `Loader` itself and avoid complications (Is only my opinion, maybe you do not prefer doing things of this manner). Sorry for my bad english again.

Comment: @BotMaster I've modified my answer and I added another aspect related with the sandbox security violation of load an `SWF` stored in different domain.

Comment: The swf is very obviously in the same domain if you look at the relative path.  What is needed is a `LoaderContext` object passed to the load method which specifes which sandbox to load it into.

Comment: Yes @BadFeelingAboutThis, I know that. I only tried to give an example to BotMaster of the advantages of use of the `Loader` instead the content of the `Loader`.

Comment: Read this article if you want a detailed explanation: http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/contentdomains/